# How to show the functions $x^3$ and $x^2|x|$ are linearly independent on the real line?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to show the functions $x^3$ and $x^2|x|$ are linearly independent on the real line ?

I know these are linearly independent because neither can be written as a constant multiple of the other for the whole real line. Is there any way to show their linear independence using Wronskian?

Comment: Doesn't the Wronskian use differentiability of the functions?

Comment: These functions are both differentiable.

Comment: yeah they are differentiable

Comment: Why don't you compute the Wronskian, then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The Wronskian isn't always enough to show linear independence.

Comment: @Théophile: this is minimum effort to ask the OP.

Comment: I suspect the purpose of this question is show that the Wronskian may be zero when the functions are independent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have taken wronskain for the cases x>=0 and x<0 separately. In both the cases they are linearly dependent (Separate cases) because Wronskain came out to be 0. But to prove them linearly independent _for whole real line_ was my question. I thought that was understood.

Comment: @VishweshwarTyagi: it's perfectly understood. Now you know that the Wronskian can't help here, which answers your question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I agree entirely. I think I misunderstood the purpose of your earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_1(x) = x^3, f_2(x) = |x|x^2$.

Note that the Wronskian $W(f_1,f_2) = 0$, so one cannot use the
Wronskian here.

Suppose
$g=\lambda_1 f_1 + \lambda_2 f_2 = 0$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.

Then $g(1) = \lambda_1+ \lambda_2, g(-1) = -\lambda_1+ \lambda_2$, and
solving $\lambda_1+ \lambda_2= 0, -\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 = 0$
gives $\lambda_1 = \lambda_1 = 0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I updated my answer after Umberto's remark.

Comment: But these two ($x^3$ and $|x|x^2$) are solutions for the linear ODE $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=0$ on $\mathbb R$, right? Then how they can be linearly independent while Wronskian is $0$ on $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @MessiLio As has been mentioned many times. linear independence does not imply that the Wronskian is non zero. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence for example.

Comment: Actually, I'd believed the extra condition ''being solutions of a second order linear differential equation'' will make equivalence between independence and non vanishing state of Wronskian. So this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077488/if-the-wronskian-is-zero-at-some-point-does-this-imply-linear-dependency-of-fun/4518815#comment10116474_4518815) need correction, right?

Comment: @MessiLio The ODE $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-{4 \over x}\frac{dy}{dx}+{6 \over x^2}y=0 $ is not defined at $x=0$, so you cannot apply the result referenced.